# parSapply much(!) slower than sapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I have the following data frame:

```
df = data_frame(x = rnorm(10^7), y = rnorm(10^7), z = rnorm(10^7))
```

I wanted to compare sapply to parSapply:

```
cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK" )
clusterEvalQ(cl, library("dplyr"))
```

When comparing the two:

```
system.time(sapply(df, function(x) order(x, na.last = T)))
system.time(parSapply(cl, df, function(x) order(x, na.last = T)))
```

I find the the `parSapply` is 10 times(!) slower than the `sapply`, while I would expect that it would be twice as fast. By the way, the `system` part of the system time is very low - the user time is equal to elapsed.

Can anyone explain why that is?

Comment: I have the same timings. You have to remember that parallelism comes with some overhead. You will see differences for large computations only.

Comment: For me the parallel version is only slightly slower. With a `FORK` cluster with 3 cluster nodes on a dual core machine it is a bit faster.